# Opening a new window to collect data and process it in main window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I have a main window, I use another window to get some values and i want to display those values in the main window, kinda like how an alarm clock would work. At first it will be empty and then second window lets you choose the time and then after that is done, I want these data to be displayed on the first window.
I want this to work similarly to how the Qmessagebox works.

```
def Add_new_schedule(self):
    if(self.TABLE_LENGTH == 5):
        self.TOAST_WARNING.setText("LIMIT REACHED!")
    else:
        from Clock import Ui_Clock
        self.CLOCK_WINDOW = Ui_Clock()
        self.CLOCK_WINDOW.show()
```

Here, the clock window is called, and after setting the values there, on clicking a button 'Ok' that signal connects to a function in the main window.

```
def Get_clock_values(self, TIME_DETAILS):

    DATA = {}
    DATA['index'] = len(self.DATA_FROM_DB)+1
    DATA['start_time'] = TIME_DETAILS[0]
    DATA['end_time'] = TIME_DETAILS[1]
    DATA['mode'] = TIME_DETAILS[2]
    DATA['node_1'] = True
    DATA['node_2'] = True
    DATA['node_3'] = True
    DATA['node_4'] = True

    self.DATA_FROM_DB.append(DATA)
    self.Clear_table()
    self.Set_table()
```

The DATA_FROM_DB is a list of dictionaries of the available schedules and I'm able to successfully append the new values inside this list.
The Clear_Table() clears the existing widgets to blank and the Set_table() is supposed to Create the new table with the newly modified list(DATA_FROM_DB).
I am able to modify the table with this logic as long as a second window is not called, i.e appending some hard coded values in the list and then modifying the table. However, with my current code, the table exists in its original state.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Please provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Suppose there is a text field in the second window, I want to pass this data back to the main window from which this second window was called, so that I can display the data in the text field on the main window.

Comment: That question is broad, and in SO it is off topic. Show what you've tried so we can help you with a specific question.To ask a good question read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We value very much that the author of the question shows what he or she is trying because it demonstrates the interest in solving his problem.

Comment: Since the lines of code are too large, I've added the code for one of the window from which the data is fetched.

Comment: https://github.com/nevinbaiju/pyqt_password.git

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45145967/edit) your question and show the most important part of your code to improve your question.

Comment: In your question you talk about 2 windows, I guess the second window is Password_window, which is the first window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is too broad I'll be giving you an example that:

1. Have the main window with a button and a disabled line.
2. The button makes it shows a second window.
3. Put information inside the line of the 2nd window.
4. This line of the 2nd window  updates the line in the main window in real time.
5. This is happening by [signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) emission.

---

So you have something like that:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(500,500)

        self.window2 = Window2(self)



        self.btn_show_window2 = QPushButton("Open Window 2")
        self.btn_show_window2.clicked.connect(self.show_window2)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.text_from_window2 = QLineEdit()
        self.text_from_window2.setStyleSheet("color: red;")
        self.text_from_window2.setDisabled(True)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.text_from_window2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_show_window2)

    def show_window2(self):
        self.window2.show()

    def close(self):
        self.window2.close()
        super(MainWidget, self).close()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_label(self, txt):
        self.text_from_window2.setText(txt)


class Window2(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Window2, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(300,200)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(parent.update_label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWidget()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Note:** *You have a 'million' ways to do that, this is just one of many approaches you can follow. For example instead of using the `textChanged` you could also have another button in the second window and only send the text back when clicking on it, in the same way the button from the first window makes the second appear.*

Comment: I used the same principle, using a signal in the second window to connect to a slot in the first one. I am able to append the data to a list, but my update widgets function does not work.

Comment: What you mean with "my update widgets function does not work"?

Comment: I have to update certain blank text labels and for that there is a function. I call this function after getting data from the second window similar to your principle. I get the data but when I call this update function. It won't change the text and all.

Comment: did u ".setText(txt)" of this label with the new value you caught from second window?

Comment: Yes. I even tried printing to check the value but the widgets won't get updated. If the second window is not called and I call this function from the main window itself by setting a hard coded value then the widgets get updated with any signal I specify. But not the case with the second window.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't figure it out just like that, I could be of better help if you had any small example to reproduce the behavior of your code. Sounds kinda weird what's going on with it not updating "(.

Comment: Or how would one get the value inside a variable from the mainwinow, kinda like how a Qmessagebox works.

Comment: Could you edit your question adding some small part of the code that I could run here and find out what's going on? That behavior seems really weird to me, I'm curious.

Comment: It was totally my mistake, understood from your simple code ofcourse. While calling the second window, I forgot to pass self to the second window, thats why the signals did not connect properly to the parent window. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: So glad to know it came right in the end, anything you need from pyqt just let me know and I'll help you if I can.